# How to restore single user data from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, database-backups

I have an application which has around 40-50 tables. Data for all the users are maintained in common tables. I am taking daily backups for my database. But if I have to restore data for single user ,i.e. I have to make changes in specific rows of all the table. Is there any efficient way or tool to do this. I am using Spring , Hibernate and Mysql db.

Comment: What do you have in place right now to ensure that users can only see their own data with the live database?

Comment: right now I have mapped each table with user table , so each row contains an user id and hence though hibernate I can manage to fetch the data of specific user.